# Cannot get video stream from CompressedImage message

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I am committing a newbie mistake somewhere here that I can't seem to figure out. I have the below sample code that does work. The second half is my attempt at getting the video feed from my robot. When launching the code, I get nothing.. not even a window.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CompressedImage
import time

class LineFollower(object):

    def __init__(self):

        rospy.logwarn("Init line Follower")
        self.bridge = CvBridge()       
        self.image_sub = rospy.Subscriber('/camera/image_raw/compressed', CompressedImage, self.camera_callback, queue_size = 1)
        time.sleep(5) 

    def camera_callback(self,data):

        try:
            image_np = self.bridge.compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
        except CvBridgeError as e:
            print(e)

      
        cv2.imshow("Full Img", image_np)

        cv2.waitKey(1)

    
    def clean_up(self):
         cv2.destroyAllWindows()

def main():
    rospy.init_node('line_following_node', anonymous=True)

    line_follower_object = LineFollower()

    rate = rospy.Rate(5) #originally 5
    ctrl_c = False
    def shutdownhook():
        # Works better than the rospy.is_shut_down()
        line_follower_object.clean_up()
        rospy.loginfo("shutdown time!")
        ctrl_c = True

    rospy.on_shutdown(shutdownhook)

    while not ctrl_c:
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The code that I am working on is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CompressedImage
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import rospy

import sys
print(sys.version)
print(cv2.__version__)

height = 480
width = 640
global_frame = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
def calculate_lane_pose(frame):


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
  

def camera_callback(self,data):

    try:
        global_frame = self.CvBridge.compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)

    height, width, channels = global_frame.shape
    print(height)
    cv2.imshow("Original", global_frame)

def lane_pose_publisher():
    # Set the node name
    rospy.init_node('lane_pose_publisher', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/image_raw/compressed', CompressedImage, queue_size = 1)
    # set rate
    rate = rospy.Rate(1000) # 1000hz

    while (1):
        rate.sleep()

        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    # cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        lane_pose_publisher()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: Is it actually printing anything out to the terminal?

Comment: It's printing 
print(sys.version) and
print(cv2.__version__)

but nothing being outputted from the camera...

Comment: that means the publisher isn't actually publishing anything; this can also be verified with `rostopic echo`. Where is the publisher defined and used at?

Comment: BTables, the rostopic that i'm subscribing to is /camera/image_raw/compressed that is putting out a jpeg format. Again, I believe it's something in my code? The example code works just fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code does not set a callback in the call to `rospy.Subscriber()`. It needs to be defined like this

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from std_msgs.msg import Float64
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image, CompressedImage
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
import rospy

import sys
print(sys.version)
print(cv2.__version__)

height = 480
width = 640
global_frame = np.zeros((height,width,3), np.uint8)
def calculate_lane_pose(frame):


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
  

def camera_callback(data):

    bridge = CvBridge() 

    try:
        global_frame = bridge.compressed_imgmsg_to_cv2(data)
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)

    height, width, channels = global_frame.shape
    print(height)
    cv2.imshow("Original", global_frame)

def lane_pose_publisher():
    # Set the node name
    rospy.init_node('lane_pose_publisher', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber('/camera/image_raw/compressed', CompressedImage, camera_callback, queue_size = 1)
    # set rate
    rate = rospy.Rate(1000) # 1000hz

    while (1):
        rate.sleep()

        if cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    # cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        lane_pose_publisher()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Comment: I get an error as follows: TypeError: camera_callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: @gup08 you were passing `self` to a non-class method. See my edit with the full code

Comment: I had tried this too. If I run it, it says self is not defined. I add self in the def camera_callback(self, data) but then I go back to having the error that says "TypeError: camera_callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)..

I'll update the code on the original post with your correction and the "self" but I still get the argument error..

Comment: @gup08 that was my fault, I missed a line. `self` should not be used in your code since in the context of the working example it returns a class instance; something your code doesn't have. Instead you should create a local `CvBridge` object and use that. See my edited code now.

Comment: Thank you BTables. Seems you're in the right direction. I got this new error: [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
Gdk-Message: 23:44:48.226: Original: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :0.

python: ../../src/xcb_io.c:259: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.

Comment: Glad my answer solved at least one problem. The error you're seeing now is a completely separate issue unrelated to the ROS side of things; it looks to me like it's related to opencv. Per SO guidelines I think it's recommended you create a new question for this.